# Table of content - latex shell for the American Economic Journal Macro

Tags: table-of-contents

I am editing a paper in the latex shell for AEA American Economic Journal Macroeconomics. I am using the \documentclass[AEJ]{AEA}. And i am completely unable to force in a table of content.
Do you guys have any guess as to why this might be the case?

best regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please give some content [pun intended] to the claim that you are "completely unable to force in a table of content". For instance, did you insert the instruction `\tableofcontents` and compile the document twice? If you did, did you receive an error or warning message? If so, what did the message say? Please be specific.

Comment: I downloaded the class from the journal's site and I see quite clearly that it does `\newcommand{\tableofcontents}{}`, which means that they disable the TOC creation. Do as they want.